# Calling dispatch in a sequence in ngrx StateManagement

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular9

I have the following code which uses ngrx for state management. I am relatively new to ngrx and while I understand that this.store.select is used to subscribe for any state change , I have the following question.

a) If we call dispatch functions one after the other like the below snippet inside select function, wont this lead to an infinite loop(considering Action1,Action2 refer to altering same State and **this.store.select(locationState => locationState.countriesState)** keeps getting executed since state changes)? will the third statement be ever called?
Is dispatch a synchronous function?

```
   this.store.dispatch('Action1');
   this.store.dispatch('Action2');
   this.router.navigation(['/confirm-region'],{relativeTo: this.route.parent })
```

**regioncomponent.ts**

```
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
    
    export class RegionComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
    storeSubscriptions =  <Subscription[]>[];
    constructor(private store : Store<TestState>)
    {
    }
    
    ngOnInit() {
     this.storeSubscriptions.push(
this.store.select(locationState => locationState.countriesState).subscribe(state =>
    {
     this.region = state.region,
     
     if(state.Status == true)
     {
       this.store.dispatch('Action1');
       this.store.dispatch('Action2');
       this.router.navigation(['/confirm-region'],{relativeTo: this.route.parent })
    })
    }
}
```

**ReducerList.ts**

```
import {ActionReducerMap} from '@ngrx/store';
    
export interface TestState
{
 countriesState : countriesState
}
export const reducers : ActionReducerMap<TestState> = 
{ 
  countriesState : countriesStateReducer
}
```

**countriesStateReducer.ts**

```
export function countriesReducer(state : countries,action: Action)
{

switch action.type {
 case Action1:..
 case Action2:..
}
}
```

Comment: Dispatching multiple actions is a bad practise https://ngrx.io/guide/eslint-plugin/rules/avoid-dispatching-multiple-actions-sequentially. That being sad, i think your code will end up in a loop, but that's exactly what you coded to be fair. My guess,  `this.router.navigation` will run, but it doesn't matter. Getting to such a point already has flaws beforehand, like the loop in this case

Comment: No you don't do this, in particular you should not be executing logic based on a selector emitting. Where you are dispatching an action to modify the data, you should be performing such data manipulation directly in the reducer based on the previous action. Regarding the router navigation, you can move this to an effect. If you add more detail to your example like what the action payloads are and what happens in the reducer I can give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If we call dispatch functions one after the other like the below snippet inside select function, wont this lead to an infinite loop(considering Action1,Action2 refer to altering same State and this.store.select(locationState => locationState.countriesState) keeps getting executed since state changes)?*

It depends. You can break the loop when you unsubscribe from it. And i think the unsubscribe happens in the onDestroy Hook. (Please let me know, if this is wrong, but you example looks like this).
If you never unsubscribe you will come into an infinite loop.

*will the third statement be ever called? Is dispatch a synchronous function?*

Yes, it will be called. And i think that is the reason, why your code still works without hanging in an indefinite loop.
When you call **router.navigate** the current component get's destroyed (i guess, but it looks like that, please validate by your own) because another route get's loaded. This means, that the current component unsubscribes from state changes and stops dispatching actions and navigating.